# Yesterday time in php

Tags: php, time

I have this code:

```
<?php echo $InfosMembre["rev_".date('j').""] ?>
```

which displays data from rev_14 table

How can I display data rev_13 from yesterday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use strtotime

```
strtotime("-1 day")
```

More specifically to get it into your format...

```
date('j', strtotime("-1 day"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've supplied returns an entry from an associative array with a key that is made by concatenating "rev_" with whatever today's day of the month is.

If you want your key to have yesterday's day of the month:

```
<?php    
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P10D'));
echo $InfosMembre["rev_". $date->format('j').""];
```

Note that you should set the DateTimeZone to whatever is appropriate.

More info here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php